# Is it Bahar Azadi Coin or Bahar Azadi coin?

Tags: capitalization

[Bahar Azadi Coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahar_Azadi_Coin) is an Iranian gold coin which are usually used as dowry agreed upon to be paid by the groom to the wife as per marriage contract. However, I wonder which capitalization rule is right in calling its name, Bahar Azadi Coin or Bahar Azadi coin? About the latter, I guess it should be OK as only Bahar Azadi is a specific name and the *coin* itself does not need capitalization, though the Wikipedia article does capitalize it.

Answer (score 3):

If the coin is unique, and there are no others like it, then you should capitalize it. If not, there's simply no need to do so.